# How to make head module being centered

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a HTML code and want to make head module being centered. I tried many ways to let my head module being centered. Such as, add a align into header tag, write a head module align css and write a ul align css and so on. But, I doesn't work though. Is there anyway to solve it? Here is my code:

```
    #main_nav{
            list-style: none;
            padding:0;
            overflow:hidden;
            display:table;
            height:auto;
            margin:0 auto;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:link,a:visited{
            color:#ffffff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            background-color: #bebebe;
            font-weight:bold;
            display: block;
            width:120px;
            padding: 9px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
    }

    a:hover,a:active{
            color:#ffffff;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            background-color:red;
            font-weight:bold;
            display: block;
            width:120px;
            padding: 9px;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
    }

    #m-mode, #m-color, #m-attribute, #m-helpdisplay,
    #m-add, #m-hide, #m-save, #m-helpmemo{
    float:left;
    }

</style>

<ul id="main_nav">
    <li id="m-mode">        <a href="#mode"         value="Mode"         id="btn-displayMode">mode</a></li>
    <li id="m-color">       <a href="#color"        value="Color"        id="btn-colorMode">color</a></li>
    <li id="m-attribute">   <a href="#attribute"    value="Attribute"    id="btn-attribute">attribute</a></li>
    <li id="m-helpdisplay"> <a href="#help_display" value="Help_display" id="btn-help_display">help_display</a></li>

    <li id="m-add">         <a href="#add_memo"     value="Add Memo"     id="btn-addMark">add_memo</a></li>
    <li id="m-hide">        <a href="#hide_memo"    value="Hide"         id="btn-displayNote">show / hide</a></li>
    <li id="m-save">        <a href="#save_memo"    value="Save"         id="btn-saveNote">save_memo</a></li>
    <li id="m-helpmemo">    <a href="#help_memo"    value="Help_memo"    id="btn-help_memo">help_memo</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: top of the code is:  <header id="menu_head" align="center">
    <style type="text/css">

Comment: I figured it out, but it's not a best way I think.       It still not on the center position on mobile invironment.  Here is my solution code:  
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 2500;
    width: 90%;

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution:

Just customize it to your liking : )

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      .container {
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
      }

      #main_nav {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: table;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      a:link,
      a:visited {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background-color: #bebebe;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
        width: 120px;
        padding: 9px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      a:hover,
      a:active {
        color: #ffffff;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        background-color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
        display: block;
        width: 120px;
        padding: 9px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      #m-mode,
      #m-color,
      #m-attribute,
      #m-helpdisplay,
      #m-add,
      #m-hide,
      #m-save,
      #m-helpmemo {
        float: left;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <ul id="main_nav">
        <li id="m-mode">
          <a href="#mode" value="Mode" id="btn-displayMode">mode</a>
        </li>
        <li id="m-color">
          <a href="#color" value="Color" id="btn-colorMode">color</a>
        </li>
        <li id="m-attribute">
          <a href="#attribute" value="Attribute" id="btn-attribute"
            >attribute</a
          >
        </li>
        <li id="m-helpdisplay">
          <a href="#help_display" value="Help_display" id="btn-help_display"
            >help_display</a
          >
        </li>

        <li id="m-add">
          <a href="#add_memo" value="Add Memo" id="btn-addMark">add_memo</a>
        </li>
        <li id="m-hide">
          <a href="#hide_memo" value="Hide" id="btn-displayNote">show / hide</a>
        </li>
        <li id="m-save">
          <a href="#save_memo" value="Save" id="btn-saveNote">save_memo</a>
        </li>
        <li id="m-helpmemo">
          <a href="#help_memo" value="Help_memo" id="btn-help_memo"
            >help_memo</a
          >
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you face any problem just let me know.

Comment: Thank you Momin! Actually, I mean how to let the head module being centered in wide position. But your solution gave me the form how to figure it out. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that I could help you Donghyun.